# Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_worksheet' failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write to a cell when a checkbox is marked using this sub

```
Sub CheckBox7_Click()
If ws1.Shapes("Check Box 7").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
ws2.Range(comment).Offset(0, 2).Value = "1"
Else
ws2.Range(comment).Offset(0, 2).Value = "0"
End If
End Sub
```

But if I just open the sheet and click the checkbox I get the Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_worksheet' failed error.

I defined the variables at the top of the module:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim comment As String
Dim rown As Integer
```

And I set the variables when the workbook opens:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
rown = 3
comment = "F" & rown
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rating test")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comments test")
End Sub
```

What is strange to me, if I first press a button with the following code in the module, I do not get the error anymore, even though it is the same code I put into the Workbook_open event:

```
Sub First_Comment()
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rating test")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comments test")

    rown = 3
    comment = "F" & rown

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help, I am a VBA novice!

Comment: Where did you define `Workbook_open`?

Comment: Are you sure the Workbook_Open Sub runs? If it does, it has to be in "ThisWorkbook" (under "Microsoft Excel Objects") and all other code has to be there too.

Comment: Yes the WOrkbook_Open is defined in "ThisWorkbook" (under "Microsoft Excel Objects") The other Code is in the Module1 in "Modules" under the same VBA Project. I am also sure the Workbook_Open Sub runs because when I add "msgbox comment" to the workbook_open, it shows me a msgbox with "F3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your global variables as `Public` otherwise the `Workbook_Open` will create and work on his own variables since they are out of his scope

```
Public ws1 As Worksheet
Public ws2 As Worksheet
Public comment As String
Public rown As Integer
```

Comment: This is not a good solution to use Public variable for a worksheet name - just apply them in the Sub directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use `ws1`directly

```
Sub CheckBox7_Click()
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rating test")
If ws1.Shapes("Check Box 7").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
ws2.Range(comment).Offset(0, 2).Value = "1"
Else
ws2.Range(comment).Offset(0, 2).Value = "0"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why is it not a good idea to use the Public variable for a worksheetname? I want to refer to that worksheet a lot of times throughout my project, if I had to set it everytime it would clutter up my code.

Comment: Because the object may be mistakenly used elsewhere. For a simple application like this, you dont need to go global.